# angular route issue in nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

I have hosted angular app in GKE using nginx. I have location as

```
location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html
    }
```

When I request http://ipaddress/fieldit loads application with http://ipaddress/field/field so that next time if I refresh the page it doesn't load the app again. I have a home component over there based on user's role I am doing navigation to their default page. If I remove that navigation then it just loads like http://ipaddress/field/home for http://ipaddress/field and  http://ipaddress/atlas/home for http://ipaddress/atlas and after that refresh will not work too.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I have explained the problem where nginx adds route in the url so one time it works and after that refresh won't work as on 2nd time nginx doesn't know what to do.

Comment: According to your nginx configuration, nginx does nothing except of delivering a file. It does not redirect or modify anything, so "nginx adds route" makes no sense to me. Then we have "don't work" and "nginx doesn't know what to do" as error description, sorry but that doesn't help to understand what's your problem. Also you describe a lot of url changes that seems to be triggered by your angular app but it's not clear what behavior is right and what is wrong. Can you simplify the question to something like "when I do xy then I get the following error but i expected xy to happen"?

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/www/ui;
            index index.html index.htm silent-refresh.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
}

location /ui/ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/www/ui;
            index index.html index.htm silent-refresh.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
        }
```

This works in all scenarios